# QuantLib 1.9 Fatal Error when Build Python

Tags: python, c++, quantlib, quantlib-swig

I had QuantLib 1.9 built already (succeeded), then I tried to install QuantLib-Python from SWIG 1.9. I worked with VS2015,boost_1_62_0 (msvs-14.0 32bit), Anaconda3, QuantLib-1.9, QuantLib-SWIG-1.9 and swigwin-3.0.10,all in the same folder.

When I did "python setup.py build" in dev command prompt for vs2015, I came across the error: Link: fatal error LINK1104:cannot open file 'QuantLib-vc140-mt.lib'. So I went to QuantLib-lib folder, found that the lib file in there is called "QuantLib-vc140-mt-gd.lib". I make a copy of it and renamed it to 'QuantLib-vc140-mt.lib'and ran build command again, this time it ran longer but I got this new error under some of the obj files "quantlib fatal error LNK2001:unresolved external symbol___imp___CrtDbgReportW"

I am really new to the subject and would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, you can't just rename the library. When you compiled QuantLib, you chose the "Debug" configuration, which gave you `QuantLib-vc140-mt-gd.lib`. To get the `QuantLib-vc140-mt.lib` that Python is asking for, use the "Release" configuration instead. (Incidentally, the compiled library will also be a lot faster...)

Comment: Nice to hear it. To make the answer more useful to other people with the same question, you can approve it so that it's explicitly marked as correct.